# Launch a single test from VS Code for an Angular service

Tags: angular, angular-test

I have a **service** with its **service.spec**.

The service is a normal class, with nothing specific to Angular, if not the fact that it is provided via Dependency Injection.

I would like to launch the tests of the **service.spec** from within VS Code, without having to launch **ng test** but also without having to change the boilerplate of the test, e.g. the use of `TestBed` and so on.

I am currently using `fdescribe` but it is not the ideal solution, since it anyways launch the entire **karma** thing which I would like to avoid.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Jest** for angular testing and it can filter tests to run only the failed or changed and can filter tests by filename or test name regexp pattern. This is not an answer to the original question but you may consider it.